# Does Cyrus SASL support userdb authentication?

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot, sasl, cyrus

I'm not finding anything that indicates it doesn't; I need to be able to authenticate virtual users. If not do I need to start using dovecot?

Comment: I'm glad to see that you researched this beforehand, but I'm pretty sure that SF will tell you the same that Google tells you. Just a heads up. Btw - dovecot is great :)

Comment: Are you refering to "userdb" as the Dovecot or Courier IMAP specific feature or do you just want to run Cyrus with virtual users and need SASL to authenticate against some sort of user database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.

For example, to use ldap as an authentication mechanism, I start `saslauthd` like this:

```
/usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a ldap -O /etc/saslauthd.conf
```

and here's content of `/etc/saslauthd.conf`:

```
ldap_servers: ldap://127.0.0.1
ldap_version: 3
ldap_search_base: dc=domain,dc=vn
ldap_scope: sub
ldap_uidattr: cn
ldap_filter: cn=%u
ldap_auth_method: bind
ldap_bind_dn: cn=binder,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=vn
ldap_bind_pw: pa$$w0rd
```